# File empty after fputcsv

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I created a file with fputcsv

```
    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');

    // Add the header of the CSV file
    fputcsv($handle, array('Name', 'Surname', 'Age', 'Sex'), ';');
    // Query data from database

    // Add the data queried from database
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        fputcsv(
            $handle, // The file pointer
            array(...), // The fields
            ';' // The delimiter
        );
    }

    file_put_contents('mycsv.csv',fgetcsv($handle), FILE_APPEND);

    fclose($handle);
 ....
```

I want to save the output on mycsv.csv but the file is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `php://output` is a [stream](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/wrappers.php.php) that works like `echo` or `print`. It means, you are writing in the standard output (maybe, your console or the browser).

If you want to write your content in a csv file, try to open this file or create it using PHP directly, instead of use the `file_put_contents`.

```
$handle = fopen("mycsv.csv","wb");
fputcsv($handle, array('Name', 'Surname', 'Age', 'Sex'), ';');
//...put your code
rewind($handle);//optional.it will set the file pointer to the begin of the file
```